# Knockout databinding of input type?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

Can you databind the type of an input control? Like something like this:

I believe I can just use the  and surround some controls so that I could have a different input control for each type when necessary. But I thought I'd check if there was a way to bind the type and change it on the fly that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `attr` binding lets you bind attribute values like:

```
<input data-bind="attr: { type: something }" />
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/h6n6oa6v/

Comment: I always forget about using attr. Thanks